# Civimobile API 4.0 QR code question

Tags: civievent

Can anybody tell me what this means? When creating a new event with the new release of City Mobile API, it gives you the option to turn on QR code generation for that event. However, it has a strange warning note that's really confusing, it reads like this:

When generating QR Code tokens, use this Event
If enabled, the QR Code for this event will be used (you can only have one event enabled at a time, enabling this event will disable all other events).

[image]

When I read this, it sounds like if I enable QR code generation for one event all of my other events will also be disabled (is that QR code generation disabled, or the event itself will be disabled and not active).

I guess I'm just really confused by this new feature and there isn't any documentation talking about its behavior. It would seem strange to me that you can only have one event at a time generating QR codes considering most organizations would have multiple events scheduled and open for registration at one time.

Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone taking a look at this.. I contacted the development team and they responded with some good news..

> Oh, thanks for your feedback!!! Yes, you are right, the message you
>   saw – incorrect. I’ll ask our developers to change the message. The
>   main thing you (and other users of CiviCRM/Events + QR code) need to
>   know that you can activate this option “QR Code” for the event only
>   once when creating the event. It wouldn’t be available later when you
>   would like to edit event and etc. That was the main information that
>   users need to know.  So, activating “QR Code” option for one event
>   does not influence other events. At the same time, many events can use
>   the “QR Code” option.
>
> Thanks, Maryana

So, I guess they just have to correct their description.. but, it's nice to know that we will have the ability to us QR codes for multiple events at the same time!!

Answer (score 1):

This option is not related to CiviMobile. Rather becomes available once you install QR code check in extension https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.qrcodecheckin

And yes, you are reading it correctly, only a single qr can be available at a time. This is limitation of this extension, unless someone codes it in a different way. But please see a discussion why it can’t be done with existing extension 
https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.qrcodecheckin/issues/6

Comment: United I misunderstood you this is incorrect. I do not have https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.qrcodecheckin extension and I have that message as well. (although qr codes aren't being sent, just a blank image that says qr code)

Comment: Supposed to say unless (not united)

Comment: Perhaps install the qr extension and see if blank image issue gets resolved. But according to your question that would support 1 event at a time. I am not sure if civimobile have integrated qrcheckin extension, but by the issue you have explained it sounds similar to what qr code readme says.

Comment: It does also support one extension. Civimobile does not generate qr codes for some reason (it says no image or unsupported type). Qr checkin extension does work though.